# std optional: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdoptional

I tried to compile the following program with different compilers (including gcc 6.1) :

```
#include <optional>
int main()
{
    std::optional<int> o1;
}
```

Output is

> main.cpp:1:20: fatal error: optional: No such file or directory #include optional

This is even true for the examples given here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional

Any clues why?

Comment: Do those "(since C++17)" marks ring a bell?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::optional` will be part of the C++17 standard, but if you want to use before then you will have to use `std::experimental::optional` instead, available in the header `<experimental/optional>`.

Comment: Indeed, this works! -> #include <experimental/optional>
    int main()
   { std::experimental::optional<int> o1;}

Answer (score 9):

It is in experimental  (TS):

```
#include <experimental/optional>
```

example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ab8d1e51680a79

```
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::experimental::optional<int> o1;
}
```