# I got a c++ example code with "#include <optional>" and has an error which I can't understand

Tags: c++, option-type

I'm first trying to understand optional in c++ (supported in g++ version 17)
But I had some error which seems pretty easy but I can't understand....

Here's easy example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Animal {
    std::string name;

};

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Animal> pets;

    std::optional<Animal> pet_with_name(const std::string &name) {
        for (const Animal &pet : pets) {
            if (pet.name == name) {
                return pet;
            }
        }
        return std::nullopt;
    }
};

int main() {
    Person john;
    john.name = "John";

    Animal fluffy;
    fluffy.name = "Fluffy";
    john.pets.push_back(fluffy);

    Animal furball;
    furball.name = "Furball";
    john.pets.push_back(furball);

    std::optional<Animal> whiskers = john.pet_with_name("Whiskers");
    if (whiskers) {
        std::cout << "John has a pet named Whiskers." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Whiskers must not belong to John." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Such an easy code and I can understand it. But I got some **errors**.

```
test.cpp:15:10: error: ‘optional’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     std::optional<Animal> pet_with_name(const std::string &name) {
          ^~~~~~~~
```

I'm running through **Ubuntu 18.04 lts in windows 10**
And it doesn't return error at

```
#include <optional>
```

and its g++ version is **g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0**

Comment: How do you compile your code? Did you enable C++17?

Comment: Did you turn on  c++17 mode for g++ ?

Comment: make sure that u used `-std=c++1z` on compiling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std optional: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253971/std-optional-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I've run code by "g++ -o -std=c++17 test.cpp"

Comment: By the way, how can I add that gray box?

Comment: `g++ -o -std=c++17 test.cpp` will generate an output file named `-std=c++17`.  You need to more careful with your option spec.

Comment: Voting to close as typo then. `-o` flag requires a single argument, the name of executable. If your code did compile, you'd end up with a file named `-std=c++17` (or an error saying that you can't name files like that). Either remove `-o` flag or provide a proper filename

Comment: Inline code can be created with by placing it in `` (backticks). See [help pages for comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Ahh.... I understand.... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your need a latest compiler and compile the above code using C++17 flag as shown below.

```
g++ -std=c++1z main.c
```

Here main.c is the file containing your code.